# The effects of overinsulating my finished ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, roofing, acoustic

I am planning to cover my finished drywall ceiling with Rockwool 80 insulation for acoustic treatment. Insulation will be covered with wood panels for a nice finish. The ceiling is vaulted and there is no attic. I am guessing this will increase R value of my ceilings. My ceiling joists and my roof will hotter in the summer and cooler in the winter. Does anyone anticipate a negative effect of this on the roof structure? I live around philadelphia, PA. I have included a picture of the ceiling below.[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Usually more insulation is not bad.  It lightens the pocket book at first but makes up for it soon after.  Blocking all ventilation to the roof is usually bad, so remember to plan for ventilation as you are packing in the insulation.

Comment: @crip659 insulation is actually added over the drywall (on the finish side). It won't actually be inside the roof. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Some people do go overboard and try to block everything.  Your type of ceiling makes this easier to do since there is less room.  Are you thinking of dropping the ceiling or adding a new lower ceiling?  if so will need to worry about any vapour barrier above the ceiling.

Comment: Yes I think  "adding a new lower ceiling" will be a very good way to describe it. Also the void between the old ceiling and lower ceiling will be insulated.

Comment: @crip659 I want to thank you for vapor barrier comment. After your comment, I changed my design so that the entire lower ceiling will be vapor permeable. This would mean that thermal insulation will be greatly reduced but I am primarly interested in acoustics anyway.

Comment: What kind of 'acoustics'? Rockwool will block some higher frequencies, but not lower. If you drywall over the rockwool you will not affect the acoustic properties *inside* the room - in fact unless you retain the slope you will make the acoustics *worse*. The sloped ceiling is a good way to prevent standing waves - at least in one direction. Recording studios have non-parallel walls & ceilings precisely because of this property.

Comment: @Tetsujin. You are right, drywall over rockwool will have no effect on acoustics at all. Instead I will have these panels over rockwool. https://www.thewoodveneerhub.com/products/luxury-american-oak-natural-core-acoustic-slat-wood-wall-panels-original-slatpanel

Comment: Ah, OK, then in effect you're building a bass trap with some higher frequency filtering - however… though I'm a sound engineer I am most definitely not an acoustician. I've paid people to build studios & trusted to their expertise. Your wood sizes & gaps are critical to which frequencies you enhance or suppress - but as to how to calculate it… I haven't a clue, sorry.

Comment: Echo in that room due to these high ceilings bothering me so much that I am willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: Is it 'smoothly ambient' or does it 'flutter', or does it 'ring'? Stand in different places around the room & clap loudly, just once. Listen to the echoes. If it's flutter, then the walls are more likely to be the culprits, as they're parallel. Is it carpeted? Do you have a spare rug you could get someone to hold up against each wall in turn & repeat the clap test?